# Need an explanation in which occasions we should use & with printf in C

Tags: c, printing, printf, output

As far as I know in c when using `printf()` we don't use &.Right?But in my programme, if I don't use it in the display function it gives me an error.Can someone explain this? Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 100
void enqueue();
char dequeue(void);
int front=-1,rear=-1,option;
char name[max][max],val;
void display(void);


void enqueue() {

    printf("Enter the name of the paitent : ");
    if(rear==max-1)
        printf("Line is full");
    else if (front==-1 && rear==-1)
        front=rear=0;
    else
        rear++;
    scanf("%s",&name[rear][rear]);

}

char dequeue(void) {
    char val;
    if(front==-1 || front >rear )
        printf("Line is empty");
    else
    {
        val=name[front];
        front++;
        if(front>rear)
            front=rear=-1;
        return val;
    }
}
void display(void) {
    int i;
    if(front==-1|| front >rear)
        printf("The queue is empty");
    else
    {
        for(i=front; i<=rear; i++) {
            printf("%s\t",&name[i][i]);
        }
    }

}



int main () {
    printf("\n\n*******Medical Cneter********");
    printf("\n\t1. Insert a paitent");
    printf("\n\t2. Remove a paitent");
    printf("\n\t3. Check Paitent list");
    printf("\n\t4. Display");
    printf("\n\t5. Exit");
    do {
        printf("\nEnter your option: ");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option) 
       {
        case 1:
            enqueue();
            break;
        case 2:
            dequeue();
            break;
        //  case 3:
        case 4:
            display();
            break;
        }

    } while(option !=5);

}
```

If I don't use & the programme will crash. As far as I know in c when using `printf()` we don't use. But in my programme, if I don't use it in the display function it gives me an error.Can someone explain this? Thank you

Comment: You don't need to understand the occasions, but the meaning of this operator. The occasions understanding will come as a bonus.

Comment: You should read the documentation for [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Really with `printf` and `scanf` you just need to know what data type the format specifier wants. That's explained in the documentation. It's not a simple rule that `scanf` needs `&` but `printf` doesn't. Beyond that, and more generally, regardless of `printf` and `scanf` you need to understand when and how to use pointers, especially when arrays are involved.

Comment: Your code does not compile for some other problems as well. At first, eliminate those errors and paste your code again, which contain only one problem that you're pointing at.

Comment: what if you changed `printf("%s\t",&name[i][i]);` to `printf("%c\t",name[i][i]);`.  Each element of the two dimensional array `name` is a single character.  So, using the `%s` specifier is wrong.

Comment: @ bruceg then it will print only the first character of the each name.

Comment: I think you want `name[i]` and not `&name[i][i]`

Comment: @ArndtJonasson thansk for the comment .I tired it .if I used name[i]  then I wont need to use &.But if I use name[i][i] then I have to use &.Anyway I got the answer.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, let's review what the `&` operator does, and what types of values we need to pass to `printf`, and also, for comparison, what types of values we need to pass to `scanf`.

If you have a thing `x`, then the expression `&x` gives you a pointer to `x`.  If `x` is an `int`, `&x` gives a pointer-to-`int`.  If `x` is a `char`, `&x` gives pointer-to-`char`.

For example, if I write

```
int i;
int *ip;
ip = &i;
```

I have declared an `int` variable `i`, and a pointer-to-int variable `ip`.  I have used the `&` operator to make a pointer to `i`, and I have stored that pointer-to-`int` in the variable `ip`.  This is all fine.

As you may know, when you call `scanf` you always have to pass pointers to the variables which you want `scanf` to fill in for you.  You can't write

```
scanf("%d %d", x, y);    /* WRONG */
```

because that would pass the values of the variables `x` and `y` to `scanf`.  But you don't want to pass values *to* `scanf`, you want `scanf` to read some values from the user, and transmit them back to you.  In fact, you want `scanf` to write *to* your variables `x` and `y`.  That's why you pass pointers to `x` and `y`, so that `scanf` can use the pointers to fill in your variables.  So that's why you almost always see `&`'s on the arguments in `scanf` calls.

But none of those reasons applies to `printf`.  When you call `printf`, you *do* want to pass ordinary values to it.  You're not (usually) asking `printf` to pass any data back to you.  So most of the `printf` format specifiers are defined as accepting ordinary values, *not* pointers-to-values.  So that's why you hardly ever see `&`'s in `printf` calls.

Now, you might think of `&` as an operator that "converts things" to pointers, but that's not really a good way of thinking about it.  As I said, given an object `x`, the expression `&x` *constructs* a pointer to `x`.  It doesn't "convert" anything; it certainly doesn't "convert" x.  It constructs a brand-new pointer value, pointing to `x`.

In the code you posted, it looks like you might have used `&` in an attempt to perform such a "conversion".  You had an array `name` of type array-of-array-of-`char`, or a two-dimensional array of characters.  You were trying to print a string with `%s`.  You knew, or perhaps your compiler warned you, that `%s` needs a pointer-to-char, and you knew (or your compiler told you) that the expression `name[i][i]` gave a value of type `char`.  Now, putting a `&` in front of `name[i][i]` did indeed get a value of type pointer-to-`char`, as `%s` requires, and it might even have seemed to work, but it's a pretty haphazard solution.

It's true that `printf`'s `%s` needs a pointer-to-`char`, but it doesn't need just *any* pointer-to-`char`; it needs a pointer-to-`char` that points to a valid, null-terminated string.  And that's why, even though `%s` needs a pointer, you still don't usually see `&`'s in `printf` calls.  You could use `&` on a single character variable to get a pointer to that character, like this:

```
char c = 'x';
printf("%s", &c);    /* WRONG */
```

But this is broken code, and won't work properly, because the pointer you get is not to a valid string, because there's no null termination.

In your code, you *probably* want to change the line

```
printf("%s\t",&name[i][i]);
```

to

```
printf("%s\t",name[i]);
```

`name` is a two-dimensional array of `char`, but since a string in C is an array of `char`, you can also think of `name` as being a (single dimensional) array of strings, and I think that's how you're trying to use it.

Similarly, I suspect you want to change the line

```
scanf("%s",&name[rear][rear]);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", name[rear]);
```

But before you say "I thought `scanf` always needed `&`!", remember, the rule is that `scanf` needs a *pointer*.  And since `name[i]` is an array, you automatically get a pointer to its first element when you pass it to `scanf` (or in fact when you use it in any expression).  (And this is also the reasoning behind `printf("%s\t",name[i])`.)

If you wanted to use an explicit `&`, what you want is a pointer to the *beginning* of the string array you want `scanf` to fill in, so I think you'd want

```
scanf("%s", &name[rear][0]);
```

instead of the expression you had.

(It looks like you were, probably accidentally, running your strings down the diagonal of the `name` array, instead of down the left edge.  It's also curious that you declared the perfectly square array

```
char name[max][max];
```

that is, 100 strings of 100 characters each.  It's not wrong, and it'll work, but it's curious, and it makes it easier to mix up the rows and the columns.)

`

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling your code and it seems I'm getting the error:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 val=name[front];
    ^
```

The reason is that `name` is a 2D array and you are assigning a pointer to a 1D array of chars to a char.

I think that in order to fully understand the problem one would have to understand how C deals with memory and pointers.

The '&' symbol means that you are taking the address of something (not to be confused with c++ references).

This means that if a function has an argument like the following:

```
void foo(char* bar);
```

and you want to pass your variable `char var;` to the function, you would have to call the function using the '&' symbol to explicitly tell the compiler that you want to pass the address of `var` as the parameter to the function.

```
foo(&var);
```

if you want to access the value of `var` inside function `foo` you would have to "dereference" the pointer so that the compiler understands that you want the value stored at the address you just passed to the function.

In order to dereference a pointer you use the '*' symbol.

```
char some_char_in_foo = *var;
```

I suggest reading up on pointers to clarify the matter further.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` conversion specifier in both `printf` and `scanf` expects it's corresponding argument to have type `char *`, and to point to the first character in a *string*.

Remember that in C, a *string* is a sequence of characters including a 0-valued terminator.  Strings are *stored* in arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for "wide" strings).

Your `name` array can store `max` strings, each of which can be up to `max`-1 characters long, not counting the string terminator.

When an array *expression* is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or isn't a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, the expression is implicitly converted ("decays") from type "array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.

`name` has type "`max`-element array of `max`-element array of `char`".  This means that each `name[i]` has type "`max`-element array of `char`", which, if it's not the operand of `&` or `sizeof`, "decays" to type `char *`.

That's basically a long-winded way of saying that the *expression* `max[i]` is equivalent to `&max[i][0]`.  So you can write your `printf` statement as

```
printf( "%s\t", name[i] );
```

Similarly, you can rewrite your `scanf` statement in the `enqueue` function as

```
scanf( "%s", name[i] );
```

although honestly, for user input it's safer to use `fgets`:

```
if ( fgets( name[i], sizeof name[i], stdin ) )
  // successful input
else
  // EOF or error on read
```

Answer (score -1):

The `&` operator means "take the reference of". `scanf` modifies its arguments, therefore, you need to given a reference to the arguments you want modified. `printf` does not modify its arguments, therefore, you can pass its arguments by value, because it can do its job with a copy.

However, this is not a final rule, as the format string `%p` will print a pointer (i.e a reference). So `printf` might need a reference to a variable in some cases.

A more general rule would be this one: `scanf` takes its arguments by reference, `printf` takes its arguments by value.

Comment: *The `&` operator means "take the reference of"*  No, the `&` does not make a "reference".  C does not have "references". `&` is the [address-of operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3): "The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ''type'', the result has type ''pointer to type''."  The "address of" something is what's in a *pointer*.

Comment: In C, a pointer, a reference and the address are pretty much the same thing. Technically you're right, if you make this rule for C/C++. For a beginner, it should be clear enough.

Comment: The problem is references and pointers are syntactically distinct.  A C++ reference of the form `int &x` is modified directly, such as `x = ...;`, while a C or C++ pointer must be dereferenced to modify the original object, such as `int *x` leading to `*x = ...` modifying the original `int` object.  And it's beginners who are most likely to get confused by that.

Comment: However, the question was limited to C, where there's no distinction whatsoever.

Comment: Except that by calling it a "reference", you called it something that doesn't exist - a C "reference".  At least calling it a "class" would have been less confusing.  You used the wrong terminology in a field where precision matters, and this answer is going to confuse people.